# Why is the message of the shutdown pop-up cut off?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, popup, shutdown-script

I am working on a prank Program that randomly reboots your pc while also doing other stuff. 
Anyways, I am currently working on the reboot part and I came up with this command:

```
shutdown -g -t 30 -d p:2:18 -c "Dieser Computer wurde von einer externen Quelle übernommen und wird momentan infiziert mit dem WannaCry Virus. Um nicht-autorisierten Zugriff auf anderen Computern in diesem Netzwerk zu vermeiden starten wir nun Ihr Gerät neu." -f
```

My Problem is that the text is being cut off because of no particular reason. This is what the pop-up looks like:

[The Pop-Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uECE.png)

I did some research on why this could happen, but I see no reason.
**/c "comment":**   This command option allows you to leave a comment describing the reason for the shutdown or restart. You must include quotes around the comment. **The maximum length of the comment is *512* characters**.

*Source: https://www.lifewire.com/shutdown-command-2618100*

Does anyone know why this could happen?

Thanks in advance

TRG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, I can reproduce using an even shorter message like "nicht-auto" or "n-a". Perhaps it interprets "-a" like a new parameter, despite being quoted. If you remove the dash "-", it works. Looks like a bug to me.

A workaround is to replace the dash by an [alternative Unicode character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm):

```
shutdown -g -t 30 -d p:2:18 -c "nicht$([char]0x2010)autorisierten" -f
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me too, you really helped me out there! Cheers!